# Summation in a least squares problem

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, least-squares

Given $A ∈ R^{m×n}$ and a set of vectors $x_i ∈ R^m, y_i ∈ R^n, i = 1, 2, . . . , k$

(a) Find a set of coefficients $a_i’s$ such that $(||A - a_1x_1(y_1)^T - a_2x_2(y_2)^T - .... -a_kx_k(y_k)^T||_2)^2$ is minimized.

(b) What are the set of $x_i
, y_i$ that minimize the minimum in (a) for $k < min(m, n)?$

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
&v = {\rm diag}(X^TAY),\quad &B={\rm Diag}(a)\in{\mathbb R}^{k\times k} \\
&X = \big[\,x_1\;x_2\;\ldots\;x_k\big]&\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times k} \\
&Y = \big[\,y_1\;y_2\;\ldots\;y_k\big]&\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times k} \\
&M = XBY^T-A &\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \\
&P = X^TX\odot Y^TY &\in{\mathbb R}^{k\times k} \\
}$$
where diag() creates a vector from the diagonal of the matrix argument, Diag() creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument, and $\odot$ represents the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Write the objective function in terms of these new variable.

Then calculate its differential and gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|\,(-M)\,\|_F^2 \\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}M:M \\
d\phi &= M:dM \\
 &= M:X\,dB\,Y^T \\
 &= X^TMY:dB \\
 &= X^T(XBY^T-A)Y:{\rm Diag}(da) \\
 &= {\rm diag}(X^TXBY^TY-X^TAY):da \\
 &= (Pa-v):da \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial a} &= Pa-v \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $a$ vector.
$$\eqalign{
Pa &= v \\
a
 &= P^+v
\;=\; (X^TX\odot Y^TY)^+{\rm diag}(X^TAY) \\
}$$
where $P^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $P$

**NB:** In some of the steps above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e. $$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$ Properties of the trace allow terms in such products to be rearranged in a number of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C \;=\; AC^T:B \\
}$$

Comment: Could you please explain on how $dM = XdBA^T$ and the next consecutive step to it ?

Comment: Oops! That was a typo. The line had been corrected to $\,dM=X\,dB\,Y^T.\,$ The following line is a consequence of the rules for rearranging the colon product.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you. So this are the optimum $a_i's$, could you give some inputs for the part (b) as well ?

Comment: Part (b) is asking for the optimal rank-$k$ approximation. First calculate the SVD of $A$: 
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^{rank(A)} \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$$
Then assuming that the singular values are ordered 
$(\sigma_1\ge\sigma_2\ge\sigma_3\ge\ldots\,)\,$
truncating the sum at the $k^{th}$ term yields the best rank-$k$ approximation.